# How to make a synchronous KafkaSpout on Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to make a Kafka consumer that syncrhonously consume messages from Kafka.

The actual problem I am having is that the queue of messages is being stored in Storm Spout.

What I am trying to do is making Storm be awaiting to Kafka ACK reply and only then let Storm consume next message.

I am using the Storm KafkaSpout:

```
/**
     * Creates a configured kafka spout.
     * @param topicName Topic where the kafka spout subscribes
     * @return An instance of configured KafkaSpout
     */
    public KafkaSpout getkafkaSpout(String topicName){
        return new KafkaSpout(this.getSpoutConfig(topicName));
    }

    /**
     * Create the necessary configuration to create a new kafka spout.
     * @param topicName Topic where the kafka spout subscribes
     * @return Spout configuration
     */
    public SpoutConfig getSpoutConfig(String topicName) {
        SpoutConfig spoutConfig=new SpoutConfig(this.getZkHosts(),topicName, "", String.join("-",topicName,RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20)));
        spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        spoutConfig.startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime();
        return spoutConfig;
    }



builder.setSpout("kafkaPackedData", stormConfig.getkafkaSpout("topic_kafka"), 2);
```

I have update to Storm 2.0.0, I use storm-kafka-client. But if I configure the 
Storm queue to 50: `setMaxSpoutPending(50);` when I send many data to Kafka, it Storm stops consuming it.

I have configured Kafka consumer with the next config:

```
KafkaSpoutConfig spoutConf =  KafkaSpoutConfig.builder("stream1:9092", "kafkaToStormAlarms")
                    .setProp(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "50000") //Set session timeout
                    .setProp(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000") //Set request timeout
                    .setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(10000)    //Set automatic confirmation time (in ms)
                    .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(LATEST)    //Set to pull the latest messages
                    .setRetry(kafkaSpoutRetryService)
                    .build();
```

When Storm consumes 50 messages same of the MaxSpoutPending configuration, it stops consuming more. Maybe the next bolt is not sending correctly the ACK? I use the next bolt after the KafkaConsumerSpout:

```
public class testBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("MQTTmessage"));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector boc) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\nLLEGA BIENN AL SPLIT TEXT BOLT\n\n");
        System.out.println("TUPLE "+tuple);
        String text = tuple.getString(4);
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\r?\\n"));

        lines.forEach(line -> {
            boc.emit(new Values(line));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding throttling the spout: Yes, you can do this by setting the `topology.max.spout.pending` option in your topology configuration to `1`. I wouldn't really recommend it, if you want to have good throughput, but I'll assume you've already considered carefully why you need the topology to behave this way.

Regarding the new spout: Is `stream1:9092` the server Kafka is running on, and is `kafkaToStormAlarms` the topic you're sending to? If not, that's probably your problem. Otherwise, check the worker logs in `storm/logs/workers-artifacts`, it may tell you why the spout isn't emitting anything.

Finally yes, you should absolutely be using `storm-kafka-client` instead of `storm-kafka`, or you will not be able to upgrade to Storm 2.0.0, or the newest Kafka versions for that matter.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is not so clear. I can have topology.max.spout.pending with value of 50 for example. But if Kafka process 90 messages Storm only can store 50 in his queue, so I am lossing 40 messages. My problem happens, when the topology.max.spout.pending is at the maximoum, it lose the messages. And it happens when I insert many messages in Kafka. Maybe with Storm 2.0.0 and the new client of Kafka "storm-kafka-client" could work better?

Yes, my kafka server is stream1:9092 and the topic is kafkaToStormAlarms. I am testing.

Comment: Yes, please switch to `storm-kafka-client`. There's an example of how to use it at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpoutTopologyMainNamedTopics.java. The new spout should never lose messages, unless you configure it to skip messages.

Comment: I just switch to Storm 2.1.0, kafka-client 2.3.1, and Kafka server 2.3.1. But the problem continue. If I have Spout max queue 50, and I add many data 1 peer second to Kafka, after some time, Storm stops consuming from Kafka. What could it be? (If I make the Storm Spout queue bigger it works better, but if I send data quiklier it would fail too)

Comment: Are you acking the tuples correctly? Maybe one or more of your bolts don't ack the tuples sometimes? Try just having a single bolt in your topology that acks. If the problem goes away, most likely one of your bolts is not acking the tuples.

Comment: I have test with the next very simple bolt, and it works fine. Because it send the ACK after printing.

public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        System.out.println("OK");
        collector.ack(tuple);
    }

But if I have a more complex Bolt, it is storing all Kafka message in the Spout queue, and if the queue is full, it lost the messages. Is not possible to control this?

Comment: Like I said, the most likely reason is that your more complex bolt is not correctly acking all the tuples. Unless you need the bolt to buffer up the tuples, I would recommend you extend BaseBasicBolt instead of BaseRichBolt. That way, acking is handled for you.

Comment: That being said, do you actually need at-least-once processing, or is it fine if some messages are lost occasionally?

Comment: Stig, I would need to proccess al-least-once. I need all the messages.

Comment: I have tried with BaseBasicBolt and the same problem. If I have a Storm queue of 50 when it consumes 50 messages from Kafka and send to the next bolt, it doesn't consume or send more to the next bolt. I just added the bolt to the description.

Comment: If I use "At-Most-Once" ProcessingGuarantee, it works perfect. But I need to ensure that al least once..

Comment: I have checked in a Kafka client, and when I use "At-Most-Once", the consumer updated his Offset but when I use "At-Least-once", the offset doesn't change. There is the problem.

Comment: Could you post an example project to e.g. Github?

Comment: Thanks!, finally it solves using AT_MOST_ONCE, or using AT_LEAST_ONCE, it commit the ACK to Kafka when all the flow ends. Maybe is little inefficient.. So I would think what could be better to use. using AT_MOST_ONCE, yo only lose messages if  Storm next bolt or completly fail?

Comment: I would accept your answer because using the new version of Storm with storm-kafka-client it works. Thanks

Comment: With AT_MOST_ONCE, you may lose messages for any reason. Basically the spout just marks messages as "done" as soon as they have been read from Kafka. So if anything crashes after that, you lose those messages.